# How can I return non-zero if upstart job fails to start?

Tags: upstart, services

How can I return non-zero from an upstart job if it fails to launch the first time?  I suspect that respawn might be the culprit here, but perhaps not.

The reason I want respawn is because myscript.py is a serivce that can exit for two separate reasons:

- Bad configuration.  (fails at startup)
- Unexpected exception when processing data. (Runtime failure)

So I'd very much like to keep the second behavior, without the first if at all possible.

```
description "MyJob"

respawn

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

script
    exec python /usr/local/bin/myscript.py
end script
```

Anyway, I could live with the dual behaviors if the initial restart or start commands return non-zero when the script exits within a small window.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is your script a service?

Comment: Does service mean something specific?

My script starts and runs until killed if that's what you mean.

Comment: Maybe daemon rings a bell? Something that continues running in the background?

Comment: I want to know if the script is meant to be running in the background all the time or if it's a one time only thingy.

Comment: Yes of course.  I thought daemon/service was implied by my question. Sorry.  I'll update it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
description "MyJob"

respawn

# retry 4 times in 3 seconds
# This should ALWAYS be true:
# 4 times * sleep .5 < 3 sec
# Otherwise it will continue respawning forever
respawn limit 4 3

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

script
    exec python /usr/local/bin/myscript.py
end script

post-start script
    # Time after starting service should unquestionably be running
    sleep .5
    if ps fax | grep '[m]yscript' ; then
        exit 0
    fi
    exit 1
end script
```

Comment: Wait, you want to know if your script is running? upstart knows if it's running already.

Comment: I want to know if it started cleanly.  Doing `sudo service myservice start` doesn't return errors if you have the `respawn` option set without the `post-start` part.  With this script, `sudo service myservice start` will return 1 if the script fails to start. (Really though, it's failing 4 times in 3 seconds the first time you start it).

Comment: Can you show the content of the script instead? The problem is within the main loop of the script (through scripts shouldn't be used for running continuously) and pre-start you can use it to do checks in the way of `mysciprt --check` for example.

Comment: "Scripts shouldn't be used for running continuously."  I respectfully disagree. There's a reason it was called SysV init_scripts_ before there was upstart or systemd.  However, you have an excellent point.  I think I'll add something along the lines of a --check that executes the script until I get to the main loop and then exit; and call that in `pre-start`.  Thanks!